# How to point one domain into another existing domain hosting?

Tags: cpanel

I want to point one domain to another existing domain.

For example I have the following two domains:

1. test1.com
2. test2.com

Now suppose I have done hosting for test2.com.  But now I want that if I open test1.com, that it should open the same content/pages which are displayed in test2.com.  I do not want to redirect from test1.com to test2.com.  URL should be same as it is i.e test1.com. Is this possible?

I have cpanel hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an url redirect record from your cpanel.

Record-

First domain will be forwarded to second domain.

Comment: i dont want to change in url. For example i have one page http://www.test2.com/contact.php. Now same contact.php should be open if i open test1.com/contact.php. is this possible ?

Comment: Then please create an A Record for your domain putting host name as @ and value will be your hosting server address.

Comment: @AshishAwasthi, is this what Bitly team does. I am creating same service as Bitly. I am also looking for custom domain shorting service where customers can add their domain and short links with their domain name should listen to my domain

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the second domain name as parked from cPanel -> Parked domains. It will achieve what you are trying to do:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Park+a+Domain

Please note however that if you are running WordPress for example, as it is a URL dependable application, it might rewrite your URL.